# C# matching regex to HHMMSS

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm using VS 2010 Data Generator to **generate** test strings based on a regular expression.

At the moment I'm having difficulty using the appropriate pattern to generate`HHMMSS` time strings.

So far I have this, but it's not wholly accurate: `([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]`

For example one desired set would be like: `212013`

Comment: The text of your question makes it unclear - will your output string have colon delimiters or not?

Comment: ah, I left the colons in from testing. Just to be clear there should be no delimiters. Just as the example shows.

Comment: So what do you mean by "not wholly accurate"? What does it do wrong?

Comment: Well judging by the correct answer below I had a `?` when its not needed.

Comment: @Lee I've added a quick line explaining why the `?` was causing you problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following should meet your format requirements:

```
([01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]
```

The section `([01][0-9]|2[0-3])` covers 00 to 23, whilst `[0-5][0-9]` covers 00 to 59.

In your original, the `?` was making the leading zero or one optional, and thus potentially generating invalid five-digit numbers.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care for regexes, how about this:

```
var r = new Random();
DateTime.FromOADate(r.NextDouble()).ToString("HHmmss")
```

Comment: OP is using a code generator. I assume its input is a regular expression, not a line of code.